# HTML: PDF Conversion

Tags: javascript, css, html, pdf

I'm required to do two things:

1. Firstly, When a button is clicked a HTML5 page would then be converted to a .PDF
2. Secondly, I would require another page where there is a table (Grid) consisting of data, Grid resides on some part of html. I need to download whole grid as a .PDF
3. Lastly, I would require to download a row from table in point 2 as a .PDF

Any pointers how this can be done.? I searched many sites but couldnt find anything useful.

Comment: You should check this JS library: [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf), you may also check this [urltopdf api](https://www.mashape.com/tkdchamp/html-to-pdf-conversion-with-css-and-javascript) or maybe choose a PHP solution using [webkithtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

Comment: Do you have any example showing its usage?

Comment: Do you have any example of your html code? This is how it finishes when one does not provide the code at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf (it is a Node pacakge and it uses PhantomJS)

You need Node installed, to create a package.json if you don't have one in your project and install the package: `npm install --save-dev html-pdf`. Look at the README for how to use.

Comment: Actually, I need to change the format in the printed PDF. I was trying to use jsPDF and PDFMAKE but couldnot find any relevant example for its usage. npm will directly convert the html to pdf which I donot want. I want to use data displayed on HTMLpage to create new pdf dynamically.